# Need help getting text from multiple lines of a text file, only after : in each line. C# Forms App

Tags: c#, forms

I've built a C# Forms application that takes multiple lines of input via text boxes, combo boxes, radio buttons, etc. and Exports them all in a specific format to a Text file,

Essentially the text document should be formatted like this:

> Section A:
> Description 1: A
> Description 2: B
> Section B:
> Description 3: C
> Description 4: D

I currently manually write in the Text Before :, and the relevant data from the form input is always after.

Every line will end with ":", however I've got lines that end there and have nothing after and lines with data after. I'm looking to basically reverse the process, I want to import the text file I exported, and grab only the relevant data and put it back into the Text Boxes, Combo Boxes, radio buttons, etc.

I basically just need to scan each line of the file and only grab the text after : (if any is present) and assign it to a variable. I can't seem to find a method for this that will parse through each line until the : like I need.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So you're asking how to use `string.Split()`?

Comment: StreamReader.ReadLine https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readline?view=net-6.0  combined with the comment above `String.Split()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the strings between each colon and check the final string for whitespace after the final colon, then you will use the `string.Split` and `string.IsNullOrWhitespace` methods. The `Split` method will "split" your colon separated string into an array of strings which you can loop through, using `string.IsNullOrWhitespace` to assess each individual string.

```
string colonSeparatedText = "beep: bop: boop: bleep: blop: "; 

string[] wordsBetweenColons = colonSeparatedText.Split(':');

foreach (var words in wordsBetweenColons)
{
    var wordsWithoutLeadingOrTrailingWhitespace = words.Trim();
    var currentLine = "Is Null or Whitespace: "  + 
        String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(wordsWithoutLeadingOrTrailingWhitespace) + 
        "   Value: " + 
        wordsWithoutLeadingOrTrailingWhitespace;
    Console.WriteLine(currentLine);
}

//Is Null or Whitespace: False    Value: beep
//Is Null or Whitespace: False    Value: bop
//Is Null or Whitespace: False    Value: boop
//Is Null or Whitespace: False    Value: bleep
//Is Null or Whitespace: False    Value: blop
//Is Null or Whitespace: True    Value:
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).